# Bootstrap DateTime Picker not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datetimepicker

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">  </script>
```

```
        <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
            <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text">
            </input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>  
   <script type="text/javascript" >  
     $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
```

I am using above same code, calender is displaying properly but when i click on time picker icon then following error coming
**TypeError: expanded.collapse is not a function**

Comment: Try some other version of datetimepicker...

Comment: @Reza yes all plugins are there, calender working properly only problem with timepicker.

Comment: @ReenaShirale Why the unaccept?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include bootstrap's collapse.js and transition.js. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery in your page before you include the other files.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>  
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">  </script>
```

Comment: i include   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> and problem resolved. sorry

Comment: Yes but the problem was originally solved because you had to include jquery first.